# setting up play framework with additional repositories

Tags: playframework

as per the documentation the following should work, but it does not look in my repo, only in central. What is missing ? The artifact and group ids are correct, as is the repo URL.

```
require:
    - play
    - com.openadex.jupiter -> jupiter.protocol 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT

repositories:
    - oaxnexus:
        type: iBiblio
        root: "http://repo.openadex.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/oax"
        contains:
            - com.openadex -> *
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still does not work on 1.2.3 --verbose shows that it does not even try to hit my repo.

Answer (score 1):

Replace type with http and root with artifact

> type: iBiblio
>
> root: "http://repo.openadex.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/oax"

to

> type: http
>
> artifact: "http://repo.openadex.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/oax"

Comment: hanks, but that still does not work on 1.2.3 --verbose shows that it does not even try to look into my repo.